# Python group by on multiple columns and plot the result?

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, matplotlib, plot, group-by

Below is how my data set looks like:

```
Levels     Role     Status
ABC        SE       Open 
XYZ        SSE      Closed 
KYZ        LA       Closed
```

Here my requirement is to get the count at each **'Level'** and for each **'role'** where status is **'Closed'**.

I am using below code to get the required result.

```
df[df['Status'] == 'Closed'].groupby(['Levels','Role']).size()
```

Now I want to plot these result. How do I plot these result. It Needs to be a self Explanatory. What kind of plot is best suit for my requirement.

I am new to visualization part.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you don't know how to visualize the result, how should anyone else know. But some kind of generic way to do it, could be to create a pivot table, where one could use one of the categories as column and the other as index and then plot a bar chart of it.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

levels=["ABC", "XYZ", "KYZ", "KYZ"]
roles = ["SE", "SSE", "LA", "SSE"]
status = ["Open", "Closed", "Closed", "Closed"]

df=pd.DataFrame({"Levels" : levels, "Role":roles, "Status":status})

df2 = df[df['Status'] == 'Closed'].groupby(['Levels','Role']).size().reset_index(name='Count')
df3 = pd.pivot_table(df2,  values='Count',  columns=['Levels'],  index = "Role",
                         aggfunc=np.sum,  fill_value=0)

df3.plot(kind="bar")
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: My apologies. I meant which would be the better way to visualize  such kind of results so it would be easy to interpret. Thanks. Its look good for me.  Just one thing that I have more than 50 values in my level column because of this its overlapping. Is any way to handle this.

Comment: What is overlapping? If it's about the legend, reducing the fontsize and or increasing the figuresize may help. You could also exchange Levels and Role, if Role has less possible entries. Different kinds of plots may also be better suited, but again, you need a rough idea of how the final plot should look like, otherwise we're digging in the dark here.

Comment: thanks. This kind of plot seems good as per my requirement. I have added this line `plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(0., 1.02, 1., .108), loc=3,ncol=8, borderaxespad=0.3)' . The legends is now readable. Only problem with the bars as colors are not well distinguishable. Anyways thanks again.

Comment: While the human brain is in general good at distingishing colors relative to each other, it's quite bad at identifying absolute colors. But this is a general problem in visualization and cannot be solved here.